# Can breakpoints of the beachline move up in Fortune's algorithm?

Tags: computational-geometry, voronoi-diagrams

In [these slides](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~barequet/teaching/cg/fa16/CG-lecture7-VD.pdf) describing Fortune's algorithm for constructing a Voronoi diagram, it is noted on page 7 that break points of the beach line can move upward. How is this so?

In most of the cases I can think of, break points always move downward. I couldn't easily think of a case where a break point would move upward.

Is there an example in which an upward break point is produced as sweep-line moves down?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a situation where the sweep line is just below a site q, whose arc intersects arcs corresponding to the same site p on both ends:
[image]